# Assembly program crashes when using AT&T syntax

Tags: windows, assembly, nasm

I recently started programming in Assembly using NASM so forgive me for any mistakes. Anyways, I've been trying to compile two very simple programs that do the exact same thing (or are supposed to), one using Intel syntax and the other using AT&T syntax. When I code it using intel syntax the program appears to work fine. However, when I try coding it using AT&T syntax, the program crashes at runtime for what I assume is a segmentation fault or something. Clearly it's not doing the same thing as its intel-counterpart so if anyone could point out what's wrong with my code, that would be great

By The Way: I am programming this on 64-bit Windows 10, however I don't think that will be very useful since the program itself does next to nothing...

Here is my code:

Intel Syntax:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.global main

main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp + 0x8]
    mov rbx, QWORD PTR [rbp + 0xc]
    mov rax, rbx

    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
```

AT&T syntax (Program crashes):

```
.global main

main:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rbp, %rsp

    movq %rax, 0x8(%rbp)
    movq %rbx, 0xc(%rbp)
    movq %rax, %rbx

    movq %rsp, %rbp
    popq %rbp 
    ret
```

Comment: at&t has operand order reversed. You need to swap all of your operands. PS: neither version is `nasm` though. It's more like `gas`.

Comment: Yep, I remembered this just as you posted it and now it works. Thanks lol. Also by NASM I mean I compiled it with NASM, what do you mean that neither version is NASM?

Comment: @Jester, sorry, my mistake. Apparently my text editor wasn't using the build system I made to compile using NASM so it was using gas instead -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Intel and AT&T syntax](https://imada.sdu.dk/Employees/kslarsen-bak/Courses/dm18-2007-spring/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm)

Yes, I just realized that the AT&T operand order is reversed so here I am answering my own question, maybe this is just an example of why you should **READ DOCUMENTATIONS AND GUIDES**

Fix:

```
.global main

main:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp

    movq 0x8(%rbp), %rax
    movq 0xc(%rbp), %rbx
    movq %rbx, %rax

    movq %rbp, %rsp
    popq %rbp 
    ret
```